# Javascript to let webserver fetch range-like requests of data from a large file on client PC?

Tags: javascript, http, file-upload, upload

When uploading a large file to a web server for processing, the upload itself can take a long time, and unless the file can be processed sequentially, the server has to wait until the entire file has been received before processing can begin.

Is it possible to make some javascript "glue" that lets the web server request specific ranges of data from a file on the client's computer as necessary? What I'm asking for is in a way the same as HTTP Range capability, only the server would be generating the requests and javascript on the client computer would be serving the data.

By doing this, the web server could process files as they're being uploaded, for example video files with important information in the footer, or compressed archives. The web server could unpack parts of a zip file without uploading the whole archive, and could even check that the zip file structure is correct before a large file is uploaded. In fact, any generic processing of a large file that can't be read sequentially could be done at the same time as the file is being transferred, instead of first uploading the file and then processing it later. Is it possible to do something like this from the browser without deploying something like java or flash?

If it's possible to read bytes as necessary from the file, it's also conceivable that the web server wouldn't need to have space to store the entire file on a local drive, but simply access the file directly from the client's drive and process it in memory. This would probably be inefficient for some use cases, but the possibility is interesting.

Comment: The File.slice() method makes it possible to read part of a file (File inherits from Blob):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob.slice
so the remaining work would be to let the web server request byte ranges during reading, and send those ranges in the order requested. Seems possible, has anyone done this?